# Understanding the perfect randomization assumption in treatment models

Tags: econometrics, causality, treatment-effect, treatment

I have a basic question on the relation between counterfactual outcomes and treatment.

---

**Notation:** Let $D$ denote the treatment, taking value in $\{0,1\}$ where $D=0$ means untreated and $D=1$ means treated.

Let $Y_0, Y_1$ denote the counterfactual outcomes.

---

**Perfect randomisation assumption**: $(Y_0, Y_1) \perp D$

---

**Scenario:** The treatment is offered to everyone; agents who are offered the treatment can decide whether to receive it.

---

**Question:** I understand that under the scenario above $(Y_0, Y_1) \not\perp   D$. I would like to know whether under the scenario above we still have $Y_0 \perp D$ and/or $Y_1\perp D$ and why.

---

**My thoughts:**

- An agent is totally described by some random features $(X,U)$ (not necessarily entirely observed by the researcher). Hence, $Y_0=g(\underbrace{0}_{\text{untreated}},X,U)$, $Y_1=g(\underbrace{1}_{\text{treated}},X,U)$, for some unknown function $g$.
- The perfect randomization assumption can be rewritten as $D\perp (X,U)$. This, combined with $Y_0=g(0,X,U)$  $Y_1=g(1,X,U)$, implies $D\perp (Y_0, Y_1)$.
- If an agent can choose whether of not to received the treatment, then $D=h(X,U)$ for some function $h$ capturing the choice-behavior of the agent. This, combined with $Y_0=g(0,X,U)$  $Y_1=g(1,X,U)$, implies $D\not \perp (Y_0, Y_1)$.
- It remains unclear to me if with self-selection we still have $Y_0 \perp D$ and/or $Y_1\perp D$.

Comment: I Think you cannot answer either question (i.e. marginal or joint indpendence) without more information about the functions $g$ and $h$

Comment: @Sebastian I believe that the failure of the joint independence is a well known fact (if agents self-select into treatment then the perfect randomization assumption fails). I've doubts for the marginal independence.

Comment: Yeah sure empirically Yes. Why exactly so you have doubts for the marginal one? The answer also of course depends on the exact setup of the experiment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have marginal independence, not even under restrictive parametric assumptions.

Let's ignore $X$ and let Y = g(U) be linear, so that

$$Y = \beta D + U. $$

Furthermore, let $D \sim Unif[0, 1]$, and $D = I(U > 0.5)$.

Then $E[Y_1] = \beta + 0.5$, but

$$E[Y_1|D = 1] = \beta + E[U|U > 0.5] = \beta + 0.75, $$

so $D$ is not independent from $Y_1$.